# How to release all the resources before next interval of windows service written in c#?

Tags: c#, service

I have written windows service in C# which runs at once in a day. After 20 days I got out of memory exception. My OnStart method:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime scheduledTime = ScheduleService();
            TimeSpan timeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow);
            log.Info("DDL Refresh Service scheduled to run at UTC " + scheduledTime.ToString());
            int dueTime = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
            timerLastOnline = new Timer(dueTime);
            timerLastOnline.Elapsed += SchedularCallback;
            timerLastOnline.AutoReset = false;
            timerLastOnline.Start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Info("Error occurred in Onstart method: " + ex.Message);
        }
        
    }
```

SchedularCallback method:

```
private void SchedularCallback(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            timerLastOnline.Stop();
            log.Info("DDL Refresh started its operations..");
            ServiceTask();                
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Info("Exception while calling Service Task: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            timerLastOnline.Start();
            log.Info("DDL Refresh Service scheduled to run at UTC " + ScheduleService().ToString());                
        }
    }
```

ServiceTask Method:

```
public void ServiceTask()
    {            
        
        log.Info("Service task started");
        RefreshDDL ddlgrp = new RefreshDDL();                        
    }
```

RefreshDDL Class:

```
public class RefreshDDL
{
    public RefreshDDL()
    {
        
       var dgc = new DynamicGroup();
       dgc.UpdateMembershipOfGroupService();                        
    }
}
```

UpdatemembershipOfGroupService Method:

```
public void UpdateMembershipOfGroupService()
    {
        try
        {
            string serviceDomain = GetDomain();
            DynamicGroups groups = RuleRetriever.getAllRules(DynamicRuleXMLPath);
            RuleCreator creator = new RuleCreator();

            foreach (var group in groups.group)
            {
                DateTime Startdatetime = DateTime.Now;
                List<string> currentUsers = new List<string>();
                try
                {
                    log.Info("UpdateMemershipOfGroup : " + group.GroupName);

                    canBeAdded = new List<string>();

                    dynamic usersJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(GrpScriptCaller.FetchMembersOfGroupService(serviceDomain, group.GroupName));
                    foreach (var user in usersJson)
                    {
                        if (user.samaccountname != null)
                            currentUsers.Add(user.samaccountname.Value);
                    }

                    log.Info("Member existing of group : " + group.GroupName + ". Member count : " + currentUsers.Count());

                    UpdateMemershipForOUService(group, serviceDomain);

                    string usersFollows = "", usernotFollows = "";

                    if (group.Rules != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Rules ruleIndividual in group.Rules)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string OU = "";
                                log.Info("Checking if filter is applied");
                                if (ruleIndividual.Path != null && ruleIndividual.Path != "")
                                {
                                    string[] OUs = ruleIndividual.Path.Split('/');
                                    int len = OUs.Length;

                                    for (int l = len - 1; l >= 0; l--)
                                    {
                                        if (l == len - 1)
                                        {
                                            OU += "OU=" + OUs[l];
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            OU += ",OU=" + OUs[l];
                                        }

                                    }
                                    OU = "LDAP://" + OU;
                                    log.Info("Filter = " + OU);
                                }

                                //List<string> usersFollowsList = new List<string>();
                                string rulesExtracted = creator.getFilterString(ruleIndividual);
                                string tempResult = "";
                                if (ruleIndividual.RuleType == RuleType.IncludeByQuery)
                                {
                                    tempResult = GrpScriptCaller.getUsersWhoFollowRuleService(serviceDomain, rulesExtracted, "samaccountname", OU);
                                    if (tempResult.Trim() != "")
                                    {
                                        if (usersFollows != "")
                                            usersFollows += "," + tempResult;
                                        else
                                            usersFollows = tempResult;
                                    }
                                }


                                if (ruleIndividual.RuleType == RuleType.ExcludeByQuery)
                                {
                                    tempResult = GrpScriptCaller.getUsersWhoFollowRuleService(serviceDomain, rulesExtracted, "samaccountname", OU);
                                    if (tempResult.Trim() != "")
                                    {
                                        if (usernotFollows != "")
                                            usernotFollows += "," + tempResult;
                                        else
                                            usernotFollows = tempResult;
                                    }
                                }
                            }                                
                            finally
                            {
                                GC.Collect();
                                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                                GC.Collect();
                            }
                        }

                        if (usersFollows != "")
                            canBeAdded.AddRange(usersFollows.ToString().Split(',').ToList());
                        log.Info("Checking include by query rule");
                        log.Info("Adding member to list of user which will be added;");
                        log.Info("Include by Query. Updated Members count : " + canBeAdded.Count());

                        if (usernotFollows != "")
                            canBeAdded = canBeAdded.Except(usernotFollows.ToString().Split(',').ToList(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
                        log.Info("Checking exclude by query rule");
                        log.Info("Removing member to list of user which will be added;");
                        log.Info("Exclude by Query. Updated Member count : " + canBeAdded.Count());

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.Message);
                    WriteTimeStamp.info(Startdatetime, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                }
                finally
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();                        
                }
                try
                {
                    UpdateMemershipForExplicitService(group, serviceDomain);

                    if (canBeAdded.Except(currentUsers, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count() > 0)
                    {
                        GrpScriptCaller.AddUsersToGroupService(serviceDomain, canBeAdded.Except(currentUsers, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToArray(), group.GroupName, "", "", "DDL Refresh Service");
                        log.Info("AddUsersToGroup");
                    }

                    if (currentUsers.Except(canBeAdded, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count() > 0)
                    {
                        GrpScriptCaller.RemoveUsersFromGroupService(serviceDomain, currentUsers.Except(canBeAdded, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToArray(), group.GroupName, "", "", "DDL Refresh Service");
                        log.Info("RemoveUsersFromGroup");
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.Error(e);
                }                    
                WriteTimeStamp.info(Startdatetime, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            }
        }            
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

All the operation are performed by the method **UpdateMembershipOfGroupService** and this method calls lots of other methods in foreach loop. This method also create lots of class objects and List object in foreach loop. I just want to release all those resources from memory immediately without waiting for Garbage Collector. Because each day memory are growing in task manager. I saw lots of things on internet but nothing worked. I was also used IDisposable interface but didn't work. I also used GC.Collect() method but didn't work. I am stuck on it since 7 days, Please help.

Comment: If you're just running code once a day, why keep a service running 24x7? Why not just have a console app run by windows task scheduler?

Comment: I totally agree with you @Damien_The_Unbeliever but we are running some Powershell script in background for Active Directory operation and they need to run under AD admin rights. Service are running in production and we just need to fix this issue not need to create another console application for same. Can you have an idea to dispose an object immediately to release everything from the memory just like closing application do?